# summing & matching cell arrays of different sizes

Tags: arrays, matlab, string-matching, cell-array

I have a 4016 x 4 cell, called 'totalSalesCell'. The first two columns contain text the remaining two are numeric.

```
 1st field CompanyName
 2nd field UniqueID
 3rd field NumberItems
 4th field TotalValue
```

In my code I have a loop which goes over the last month in weekly steps - i.e. 4 loops.

At each loop my code returns a cell of the same structure as totalSalesCell, called weeklySalesCell which generally contains a different number of rows to totalSalesCell.

There are two things I need to do. First if weeklySalesCell contains a company that is not in totalSalesCell it needs to be added to totalSalesCell, which I believe the code below will do for me.

```
    co_list = unique([totalSalesCell(:, 1); weeklySalesCell (:, 1)]);
    index = ismember(co_list, totalSalesCell(:, 1));
    new_co = co_list(index==0, :);
    totalSalesCell = [totalSalesCell; new_co];
```

The second thing I need to do and am unsure of the best way of going about it is to then add the weeklySalesCell numeric fields to the totalSalesCell. As mentioned the cells will 90% of the time have different row numbers so cannot apply a simple addition. Below is an example of what I wish to achieve.

```
totalSalesCell                weeklySalesCell                  Result

co_id      sales_value        co_id      sales_value           co_id      sales_value
23DFG      5                  DGH84      3                     23DFG      5
DGH84      6                  ABC33      1                     DGH84      9
12345      7                  PLM78      4                     ABC33      1
PLM78      4                  12345      3                     12345      10
KLH11      11                                                  PLM78      8
                                                               KLH11      11
```

Comment: I am assuming `sales_value` are `double` values, aren't they? And `co_id` as all `char/text`.

Comment: Would it be okay if `ABC33` row from the second cell array is appended at the end of the output, i.e. `ABC33 1` comes at the end and not as the third row in the output?

Comment: yes that's fine the order is unimportant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following codes must take care of both of your tasks -

```
[x1,x2] = ismember(totalSalesCell(:,1),weeklySalesCell(:,1))
corr_c2 = nonzeros(x1.*x2)
newval = cell2mat(totalSalesCell(x1,2)) + cell2mat(weeklySalesCell(corr_c2,2))

totalSalesCell(x1,2) = num2cell(newval)
excl_c2 = ~ismember(weeklySalesCell(:,1),totalSalesCell(:,1))
out = vertcat(totalSalesCell,weeklySalesCell(excl_c2,:)) %// desired output
```

Output -

```
out = 
    '23DFG'      [ 5]
    'DGH8444'    [ 9]
    '12345'      [10]
    'PLM78'      [ 8]
    'KLH11'      [11]
    'ABC33'      [ 1]
```

Comment: yep spot on as usual! Thanks